# 2 external monitors with Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display

Can I connect two external monitors to my Macbook Pro's (non-retina, mid-2012) mini displayport ? I got one mini displayport to dvi converter and dvi-male to 2*dvi female splitter but this setup didn't work. My question is, can I use one display port to connect to two different monitors (both the monitors should be independent and not mirror)

Comment: This is a dupe, but to directly answer your question - No, you cannot connect two monitors to a single mDP port and have them independent.  See the dupe answer for how to accomplish this.

Comment: 15" or 13"? It may make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2012) - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp694?locale=en_US), this is what's supported under **Graphics and Video Support** and **Thunderbolt digital video output**:

> **Graphics and Video Support**
>
> - Intel HD Graphics 4000
> - NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M with 512MB of GDDR5 memory (15-inch 2.3GHz configuration) or NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M with 1GB of GDDR5 memory
>     (15-inch 2.6GHz configuration) and automatic graphics switching
> - Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to   2560 by 1600
>     pixels on an external display, both at millions of colors
>
> **Thunderbolt digital video output**
>
> - Native Mini DisplayPort output
> - DVI output using Mini DisplayPort to DVI Adapter (sold separately)
> - VGA output using Mini DisplayPort to VGA Adapter (sold separately)
> - Dual-link DVI output using Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter (sold separately)
> - HDMI audio and video output using third-party Mini DisplayPort to HDMI Adapter (sold separately)