# Adding third display to a MacBookPro via Thunderbolt port ?

Tags: display, thunderbolt, hdmi

I have a Mid 2012 13" MacBook Pro (MD102B/A). It has 1x Mini Display / Thunderbolt Port and 2x USB 3.1 Gen 1 ports.

At my desk I need a bigger setup, so I connect the MacBook Pro to a 24" monitor using a Mini DisplayPort to HDMI adapter.

I wish to add a second 24" monitor to my setup, so that I have 2x external monitors plus my 13" MacBook Pro screen all in the use at once. I want to use each monitor as a separate extended display, not as mirrored displays.

I have done this in the past about 4 years ago when connecting a Mac mini to 3 screens and I have used the HDMI out, Thunderbolt out, plus a USB to HDMI adapter, but the USB to HDMI adaptor made the 3rd screen quite laggy.

Is there a more up to date way to do this using a Thunderbolt splitter or hub? I have found a few online including a [Belkin one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Belkin-Connecting-Thunderbolt-Ultrabook-Ethernet/dp/B00NA6NIM8/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?ie=UTF8&qid=1527334690&sr=8-2-spons&keywords=usb%20to%20hdmi%20mac&psc=1) and a couple made by StarTech but wondered if they where going to work with the MacBook Pro. I don't believe my MacBook Pro has the most up to date Thunderbolt, although it does have 1 GB of dedicated GPU.

Comment: And asked/answered [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308622/2-external-monitors-with-macbook-pro?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308723/connecting-dual-dell-u2415-monitors-to-closed-macbook-pro-15-retina-mid-2012?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43594/dual-monitors-with-macbook-pro?rq=1) as well.

Comment: @Allan - I would say its not a duplicate as the other examples above are older questions and answers related to using the USB external graphics card route, which i mentioned in the original question as not being the solution i was looking for. My question is related to achieving the solution via the mini display port / thunderbolt port. Based on that can we un mark the question as duplicate.

Comment: just to circle back to your comment.... The question is still the same - you want multiple monitors.  You can't just hang monitors off a machine without having graphics adapters.  Your MBP can *only* support itself and a mDP connection and you either get that with a eGPU in a TB enclosure (expensive and obsolete for your TB1 setup) or a USB adapter.  A dock doesn't do this.

Comment: @Allan I thought the way it would work is that the 1x thunderbolt / mDP port on the MBP would have enough bandwidth to deliver video signal for 2 screens and that the hub was just allowing me to split that across multiple screens. (Similar to how a USB hub allows you to gain extra USB ports.) Just so i understand dose each additional screen add load to the GPU and if so dose Apple hard limit the GPU load, by capping the quantity of screens attached

Comment: @Allan similarly ive been looking at the Dell display i have and it supports daisy chaining a second display through it, although the screens can support it will it be the limitation of my MBP that will stop it having 2x extended displays

Comment: DisplayPort bandwidth is one thing, graphics chip support is something else.  It's not so much "Apple allows" or they "cap" it's just a limitation of the hardware.  If you want more monitors, you need more graphics chips.  A USB graphics adapter off loads some of that your CPU (not efficient, but it works).  If you think about it in PC's to get multiple monitors you *add* video cards (some support two out of the box).  You want 5 monitors, you need 5 cards.  Same thing on a Mac, except the PCI bus (where you plug the cards) is on the Thunderbolt port.

Comment: @Allan ah ok, would it work then if i used 2x external displays and closed my laptop display so that in total 2x displays where being used. This way i could have 2x 24" monitors attached.

Answer (score 1):

You can [daisy-chain](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9087/does-thunderbolt-support-chaining-multiple-monitors-to-a-macbook-pro) 2 Apple Thunderbolt Displays. If the first is an Apple Thunderbolt Display, you might be able to do MiniDisplay Port to HDMI off that display to a third-party HDMI monitor.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if the feature is available on a non Apple display eg a Dell or Samsung ?

Comment: If the first device is a true thunderbolt device, it's own tb ports present the same bus to downstream devices. I don't know if any 3rd party displays are true TB displays. We do it with multiple Apple TB displays. Any setups with Dell displays are using a docking hub and some HDMI.

Comment: Remember to accept the eventual best answer ;)